# vercel config for node js + prisma project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, backend, prisma, vercel

i am using prisma + nodeJs and i want to deploy it on vercel but is show error can anyone provide vercel.config for it.

```
{ 
   "version": 2, 
   "name": "backend-server", 
   "builds": \[ 
         { 
            "src": "app.js", 
            "use": "@vercel/node" 
         }, 
         { 
           "src": "prisma/schema.prisma", 
           "use": "@prisma" 
         } 
        \], 
   "routes": \[
         { 
           "src": "/(.\*)", "dest": "app.js" 
         }
        \] 
}
```

how can fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.